# Sliding through a gallery of photos on a timer

Tags: javascript, image

I am currently creating a website for a friend and I'm having an issue I can't seem to figure out. I am sure its a simple method call to what I already have. So the problem seems to be that after the slider reaches the end of the photos it just shows a blank screen and doesn't reset to the start again. what would I need to call or what method would I need to make in order to get this to work correctly. It already works when using the arrows themselves but not the auto slide. Thank you in advance.

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

//Slides after aprrox 10 seconds
function startTimer() {
  setInterval(slideRight, 10000);
}

// Init slider
function startSlide() {
  startTimer();
  reset();
  sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}

// Show next
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
});

// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the right arrow, you use this code:

```
if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
  current = -1;
}
```

...to make sure you stop and the end of the images and don't try to go too far. But your setInterval() calls slideRight() directly, which has no protection against going too far.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, current should be reset to zero as you call slideRight() and fall off the end of the array.
    // Show next
    function slideRight() {
      reset();
      if (current > sliderImages.length -1) {
         current = 0;
      }
      sliderImages[current].style.display = "block";
      current++;
    }

Incidentally, you might want to take a look at bootstrap carousel feature https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it by using carousol type function here is the code I used to replace the startSlide function, Thank you all for the help!

```
function carousel(){
   reset();
   current++;
   if (current > sliderImages.length){
     current = 1
    }
   sliderImages[current-1].style.display = "block";
   setTimeout(carousel, 7000);
}
```